# How to adapt layerswitcher to include listboxs

Tags: openlayers

For my project I needed something that allowed the user to change the application´s layers and the best solution I found was this one layer switcher since openlayers 3 does not support a layerswitcher by default. This solution allowed me to do so with ease ... until I noticed that I had way too many options and that checkboxs were not enough... I tried editing as much as I could so it could display a listbox but I have a problem. The box is being filled correctly but when I try to change a value it always selects the last option.

This is the code I edited

```
ol.control.LayerSwitcher.prototype.renderLayer_ = function(lyr, idx, selectList) {

var this_ = this;
var li = document.createElement('li'); 
var lyrTitle = lyr.get('title');
var lyrId = lyr.get('title').replace(' ', '-') + '_' + idx;
var label = document.createElement('label');

if (lyr.getLayers) {

    li.className = 'group';
    label.innerHTML = lyrTitle;
    li.appendChild(label);
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    li.appendChild(ul);
   this.renderLayers_(lyr, ul);

} else {

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    var option = document.createElement("option");

    if (lyr.get('type') === 'base') {
        input.type = 'radio';
        input.name = 'base';
        option.value = idx;
        option.text = lyrTitle;
        option.name = 'base';
        selectList.appendChild(option);           
    } else {
        input.type = 'checkbox';
    }
    input.id = lyrId;

    option.selected= lyr.get('visible');
    selectList.onchange = function (e) {
        alert(e.target.selectedIndex);
        this_.setVisible_(lyr, e.target.selectedIndex);

    };
    li.appendChild(selectList);

    input.checked = lyr.get('visible');
    input.onchange = function (e) {       
        this_.setVisible_(lyr, e.target.checked);
    };
    li.appendChild(input);

    label.htmlFor = lyrId;
    label.innerHTML = lyrTitle;
    li.appendChild(label);

}

return li;
};
```

and

```
ol.control.LayerSwitcher.prototype.renderLayers_ = function(lyr, elm) {
var lyrs = lyr.getLayers().getArray().slice().reverse();

var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.id = "mapTypes";
selectList.size = 5;

for (var i = 0, l; i < lyrs.length; i++) {
    l = lyrs[i];
    if (l.get('title')) {
        elm.appendChild(this.renderLayer_(l, i, selectList));
    }
}
};
```

I know I have to change something in the onChange function but I am not that good with javascript so i am a little bit lost on what to do next.

(the onChange function)

```
ol.control.LayerSwitcher.prototype.setVisible_ = function(lyr, visible) {
var map = this.getMap();
var selectedid = 2;

lyr.setVisible(visible);

if (visible && lyr.get('type') === 'base') {
    // Hide all other base layers regardless of grouping

    ol.control.LayerSwitcher.forEachRecursive(map, function (l, idx, a) {

        if (l != lyr && l.get('type') === 'base') {
            alert(lyr);
            l.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
};
```

I left the input/radio button implementation since it helps with debugging

And this is the "original" js file Original JS

What would I need to change to have a fully functional listbox?
Or is there a better way to have a similar implementation that uses listboxs to change the layer?